# Sampling from probability distribution via multiplying probabilities by a uniform random number

Tags: probability, sampling

When reading about a certain piece of software ([NUS ScheduleTool](http://sbtools.uchc.edu/nmr/sample_scheduler/#algorithm), for generating nonuniform sampling schedules for biomolecular NMR spectroscopy), I found the following curious method for drawing $N$ unique points given a discrete probability distribution:

Suppose we have a discrete set $S$ with a probability mass function $p\colon S \to [0,1]$ (summing to $1$). For each point $x \in S$, multiply its probability mass $p(x)$ by a random number drawn from a uniform distribution on the unit interval $[0,1]$ to get a new number $g(x)$. Sort the points in descending order by their values of $g$ and pick the $N$ first ones (where $N \leq |S|$).

Does this process have anything to do with the usual method of sampling without replacement? Is it possible to relate the distribution of the drawn points to the original distribution in any simple way?

Comparing this to the `numpy.random.choice` implementation of conventional sampling without replacement, I found that the resulting point distributions do look noticeably different (in the case of an exponential distribution where $S$ is a 2D grid, anyway). So it seems that the methods really give different results (unless there is some issue with the way I'm using their software).

I do not know the software authors' motivation for using this method. Since they did not provide any reasons for it, I'm inclined to suspect that this was an ad-hoc attempt to reproduce conventional sampling, but a more charitable interpretation is that there is some good reason for doing it this way.

---

To clarify what I mean by conventional sampling without replacement: I assume that we know how to draw one item from a nonuniform distribution $p$ (for example, sending a uniform variable through the inverse CDF to get an element index). Then, sampling multiple items without replacement means:

- Draw the first point $x_1$ from $p_1 := p\colon S \to [0,1]$.
- Draw the second point $x_2$ from $p_2 \colon S \setminus \{x_1\} \to [0,1]$.
- Draw the third point $x_3$ from $p_3 \colon S \setminus \{x_1, x_2\} \to [0,1]$.
- ...

where, at each stage, we get a new distribution by removing the sample we just drew, and adjusting the normalization: $p_{i+1}(x) = \frac{p_i(x)}{1 - p_i(x_i)}$.

I'm pretty sure that this is equivalent to repeatedly sampling *with* replacement, discarding any duplicates: E.g. for the first step, if we've drawn $x_1$ we keep drawing until we get an $x_2 \neq x_1$. So for $x \neq x_1$:
$$ p_2(x) = p(x) + p(x_1) p(x) + p(x_1)^2 p(x) + \cdots
= \frac{p(x)}{1 - p(x_1)},$$
the same as before.

To be fair, I'm not sure how "conventional" these methods are.

Comment: You have values: 1 and 2 with equal probabilities. The result of multiplication is 0.5 and 1. What do you do next? How to select the 50 smallest values?

Comment: @zoli To select 50 items you would need to start with at least 50 items. You only select each item at most once.

Comment: What is a point $x$ then?

Comment: @zoli I've made some clarifications, let me know if it's still unclear!

Comment: [The documentation of numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) doesn't define what it does if you sample with non-uniform probabilities without replacement. You seem to be aware of a "usual method of sampling without replacement" with non-uniform probabilities. I'm not aware of such a standard method; I think you should define what you mean by this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I agree that your method is equivalent to discarding duplicates, and thus to the method at the end of Mike Earnest's answer. But from the NUS documentation you link to, it seems that the "summing to $1$" premise doesn't actually apply there -- they assign "probabilities" between $0$ and $1$, but these "probabilities" don't sum to $1$; in fact, the first of them is $1$. You may have put too much stock in them calling these weights "probabilities" -- I think they're simply part of a heuristic method of generating useful sample schedules for their purposes.

Comment: That is true. I left that out of my question because it seemed like an unimportant normalization issue, but maybe it's not quite so simple...

Comment: @EliasRiedelGårding: I agree that the numbers can easily be turned into probabilities by normalizing them; I just think that, since your question revolves around their intentions, it's relevant that they call unnormalized weights "probabilities", since it seems to suggest that they're not actually interested in sampling from a well-defined distribution but rather in assigning heuristic weights.

Comment: @joriki You're right, especially since they constrain those "unnormalized" weights to lie between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your set $S$ had just two points, $x$ and $y$, where $p(x)=\frac13$ and $p(y)=\frac23$. Now, suppose you used this method to draw a sample of size $1$. What is the probability the sample is $\{x\}$?

You would expect it to be $1/3$, right? However, this method would pick $\{x\}$ with probability $1/4$. Indeed, if one variable $U$ is uniform on $[0,\frac13]$, and another $V$ is uniform on $[0,\frac23]$, then $(U,V)$ is uniform on the rectangle $[0,\frac13]\times[0,\frac23]$, and the region where $U\ge V$ is a triangle of area $\frac12(\frac13)^2=\frac1{18}$, which is one fourth of the total area $\frac13\cdot\frac23=\frac29$.

I would say their sampling method is a heuristic, and a pretty flawed one at that.

---

Furthermore, I think there is only one random process consistent with the description "sample from a distribution without replacement." Generate a list $X_1,X_2\dots$ of independent samples from that distribution. Scan the list from beginning onwards, putting every value you see in a bucket unless an earlier equal value was already put in the bucket, until the bucket has $N$ items.

A good question would be if there is a clever, "one-shot" way to simulate a sample according to this process...

**Edit:** Answering my own question, there is such a method! For each $x\in S$, let $Z_x$ be an exponential random variable with rate $p(x)$. If you choose a subset of $S$ corresponding to the indices of the smallest $N$ values of $\{Z_x\mid x\in S\}$, then the resulting set exactly has the distribution described.

Comment: Wow, you *just* beat me to it.  That's pretty incredible for a two-hour-old question.